Book about a college(?) age girl who moved into a house with several male roommates, one of whom is either a ghost or cursed
I'm trying to find this book I read in like junior high/high school and don't remember much. I graduated in 2017, if that helps any.
I know it's about a college(?) age girl who moved into this house. Her roommates are all guys, I believe. One of them is a ghost? Or cursed. I'm not sure. But he can only be in physical form at night and like completely vanishes during the day. He also can't leave the house?
It's driving me insane please help. I can't find anything on it. 
